# Work as freelancer while tourist in US for an already existing US client?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, work, freelance

I already am freelancing for a client who is from the U.S. We were supposed to file for H-1B this year. Due to unforeseen incidents we were not able to do so.

Is it possible to visit US on a tourist visa and freelance from there?

Maybe even rent a house to stay?

Comment: If you're only going for *a few weeks* it is utterly normal to do this.  A zillion people a week do this.  Note that it is TOTALLY OK to go for "meetings".  Read here:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/123350/19233 which explains the whole thing.

Answer (score 7):

No. This will be considered willful violation of your visa terms and is illegal to do. As the name suggests, your intent of entering the US is as a tourist not as a worker. By law, you cannot be compensated for any 'work' that you perform while you have entered as a tourist. You can surely rent a house to stay though.

Comment: To be somewhat more precise, it's entirely *possible* to enter the US on a tourist visa and freelance, it just isn't *legal*.  The odds of getting caught depend mostly on how good you are at faking being a tourist when applying for a visa and/or being questioned by Immigration.  And if you are busted working illegally, you can forget about ever getting an H1B...

Comment: @jpatokal sure. I just didn't want to be an accomplice in aiding and abetting even by stating the obvious.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  (1) you are **totally, 100%, allowed** to go for MEETINGS AND BUSINESS DEVELOPMENT.  (2) if you literally state the literal word, I will be "working", you can't do that.  But nobody states the word "working".  You just say "I'm going for a few meetings".  Of course, obviously, self-evidently, a zillion people a day come to the US for business, it is utterly, totally OK and proper to go to the US for a few weeks to see your clients.