# Which visa for a remote freelancer with a US client traveling to the United States?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, h1b-visas, freelance

I'm a freelancer currently working remotely for a US client. They'd like me to stay with them for a short amount of time (1-2 weeks). Purpose of this trip is to attend meetings and work there for the duration of my stay.

Would this be possible with a B1 visa? Or would it require the H1B?

I was also thinking of taking a few weeks off and extending my stay for pleasure, could this be done on either of these visas?

Comment: Are you employed directly by the US client (ie: did you have to fill out a W-8BEN form?), or do you work for (and are being paid by) a company in your own country that has sold services to your US client?  The details of your relationship with the client matter.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'm self-employed. I work through a company of which I am the owner of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Purpose of this trip is to attend meetings and work there for the duration of my stay. Would this be possible with a B1 visa?

This is kind of a grey area as B1 visas are supposed to be used for business, but there isn't a precise definition of what "business" is. Washing someone's car is definitely not a form of doing business. Attending a meeting is usually business. But what about doing some coding after the meeting is over? That's where the grey area begins.

But as a general rule you should be okay. Simply make sure to **never** mention the word "work" when you arrive in front of an immigration officer in the US. Say you are there for meetings, team building, discussion of projects, etc, but not "work". Presumably that's the truth in your case - you are only going to visit the US to do things which are hard to resolve remotely.

Source: visiting the US on a B1 visa to meet with colleagues.

> I was also thinking of taking a few weeks off and extending my stay for pleasure, could this be done on either of these visas?

If you're admitted as a B1 visitor you may also engage in tourist activities. No extra visas are required for that purpose.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the visa is a B-1/B-2 or just a B-1.  The bearer of a B-1/B-2 visa is always admitted in either B-1 or B-2 status.  A visitor in B-1 status is allowed to engage in tourism or other pleasure activities during a business visit.

Comment: Is this correct? It certainly would be if the asker worked for and was being paid by a non-US company, but the asker is proposing to work for and be paid by a US company. I was under the impression that this isn't allowed on a B-visa.

Comment: This is dicey advice.  We don't currently know enough to suggest the correct course of action for OP.  Getting this wrong can result in serious trouble.

Comment: @DavidRicherby OP cannot be *directly* working for the American company. If he follows the local laws in his state, he is either self-employed or working for the local subsidiary of the American company. When foreign employees of Microsoft or IBM travel to the US nobody bats and eye, since they're technically employed by a foreign company.

Comment: Being a freelance contractor is very different from being an employee of some corporation who normally works in country X but is briefly visiting the USA (regardless of whether the corporation is headquartered in the USA).

Comment: Thank you, another thing I read was that you shouldn't get paid by an American company while you're there. How would this work in relation with me being there?

Comment: @potorr This is why it's important to understand your relationship with the client.  In this case it sounds like you (the individual) are being paid by a company in your own country which you simply happen to own.  In this case you are not an employee of the US company and are not being paid by them at all - they are paying your company for services and you are an employee of that (foreign) company.  In this capacity you are simply visiting for business and are not being paid by the US company for work (ie: you are not their employee).  You send them an invoice, you aren't on payroll.

Comment: @potorr That said, IANAL, and sometimes the foreign-employee-wearing-a-"company"-umbrella scheme doesn't always play out with authorities.  Depending on the circumstances and the type of work you do you may still be considered an employee due to the specifics of your relationship, even if you have put a company hat on yourself.  I'm not sure what the specific rules are in the US regarding this.

Comment: @J... staying for 1-2 weeks is generally okay regardless. My answer would be different if OP wanted to stay for 1-2 months.

Comment: Thanks again guys. One final question: Would the American company providing accommodations and travel costs be an issue?

Comment: @potorr the recommended approach is to pay for them through your company and then have the American company reimburse your expenses.

Comment: I was in exactly the same situation as the OP for about 10 years. I owned my own company and had a customer in the USA, who I visited occasionally, typically for between 1 and 4 weeks at a time, paid for by the US company and I had a B1 visa to do so. As already noted, avoid mention of 'working' in the US - you're 'doing business', 'attending meetings', 'negotiating contracts', etc ... My first trip was viewed with some suspicion by the visa officer (and i was only granted a short-term visa for the exact dates I had requested), but following visas were issued for 2 years, followed by 10 years.

Comment: @brhans you should add that as a separate answer

Comment: @JonathanReez - not sure that I'd be adding any new facts which you haven't already written - just my own anecdotal evidence that your answer reflects my experience...

Answer (score 7):

- The relationship with your client is totally irrelevant
- Where and when you get paid is totally irrelevant
- Whether you own or do not own your own business is totally irrelevant
- Whether the client is paying you, or your business, is totally irrelevant
- Whether the company is a US company or a foreign company is irrelevant (it's quite common to meet, say, your Japanese client in the US for some reason)

The **ONLY THING** that is relevant is this:

## If you are there for MEETINGS

you are totally OK.  That is the very purpose of the visa.

## If you are there for "work"

you cannot do that.

That's all there is to it.

Thus you literally said:

> Purpose of this trip is to attend meetings and work there for the duration of my stay.

If on arrival you say the words "I'm here to work for two weeks" the officer will roll his eyes, mumble "why did you say that" and send you home to Europe.

If on arrival you say the words "I'm here to meet my client Massive Engineering for a couple weeks" he'll just wave you in, like the other 60% of people on the plane in the identical situation.

That's the deal.

Note that anyone who has actually done this (and vast numbers of folks do) will explain this to you.  For example, see the excellent example by @brahms in the comments.

---

Yes, in reality you'll probably do some "work" while you're there.  100.000% of people do this.  It's not as if you will sit there and say "I can't open my laptop and do one line of code". In fact, you *actually can't* open your laptop and do one line of code, as that is "work", by the letter.  But the reality is everyone does that. If you're only talking a couple weeks now and then, that's how it goes down.

Comment: I love your unorthodox style of writing answers. Your answers have personality.

Comment: That's a very kind thing to say, thanks @HankyPanky !!